# How to use categories with Sprig's "Load More" recipe

Tags: craft3, plugins, categories, relatedto

I am trying out Sprig's ["Load More" Recipe](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig-cookbook?page=2#load-more) and I am trying to call up entries that are related to the current category page. But when I add `.relatedTo(category)` to the entry model, it doesn't work–it still just shows all the entries in the channel. I've used this `.relatedTo(category)` method elsewhere on the page (not using Sprig) and it works just fine. How can I call up only the entries that match the current category page in this Sprig recipe?

**_category.twig**

```
{{ sprig('_layouts/_categories/_loadMore', {limit: 6}) }}
{{ sprig.script }}
```

**_loadMore.twig**

```
{% set offset = offset ?? 6 %}
{% set limit = limit ?? 10 %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('aBetterPost').offset(offset).limit(limit).relatedTo(category).all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="more-post">
        <div class="more-post-img-wrap">
            {% set featuredImage = entry.featuredImage.one() %}
            <img src="{{ featuredImage.getUrl }}" class="more-post-img">
            <div class="red-overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="more-post-content">
            <div class="more-post-title">
                <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="next-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

{% endfor %}

            
{% if entries %}

<div class="load-button-wrap" s-target="this" s-swap="outerHTML">
    <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="{{ offset + limit }}">
    <button class="load-button" sprig>Load More</button>
</div>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

{{ sprig('_layouts/_categories/_loadMore', {limit: 6, category: category}) }}

{{ sprig.script }}

After query category is not defined.