# How to use Sprig's "Load More" Recipe After Update

Tags: craft3, categories, relatedto, plugin-sprig

This is a continuation of a previous question I had [(Here)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35839/how-to-use-categories-with-sprigs-load-more-recipe). I am using [Sprig's Load More Recipe](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig-cookbook#load-more). In my category page, I want the load more function to only pull up entries that equals the current category page. In a recent update, the category solution that was in my previous question no longer works, since it has been restructured a little. I cannot figure out how get the `relatedTo(category)` to work again. I currently have it set up like this (the `{'relatedTo': category}` does not do anything):

_category.twig

```
{{ sprig('_layouts/_blog/_categories/_loadMore', {'limit': 6},{'relatedTo': category}) }}
{{ sprig.script }}
```

_loadMore.twig

```
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('caseFiles').offset(offset).limit(limit).relatedTo(category).all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
   ------Entry Content-----
{% endfor %}

{% if entries %}
  {# Increments `offset` by the value of `limit` and swaps itself out on click #}
  <button class="orange-button" sprig s-vars="offset: {{ offset + limit }}" 
    s-target="this" s-swap="outerHTML">
    <p>Load More</p>
  </button>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `.relatedTo(category)` but the variable you are passing is called `relatedTo`, not `category`.

Just like with `limit`, based on your code, it should be `.relatedTo(relatedTo)`. Also, it should be part of the same hash as your `limit`.

However, you can't pass a category object to a component and will need to pass its `id` instead ([docs](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/sprig#component-variables)).

Depending on what `category` is in your case (and I guess it's an object), you could do:

```
{{ sprig('_components/load-more', {
    'limit': 6,
    'categoryId': category.id
}) }}
```

Then in your component:

```
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}

{% set query = craft.entries().section('caseFiles').offset(offset).limit(limit) %}

{# Make sure a categoryId is being passed #}
{% if categoryId %}
    {% set query = query.relatedTo(categoryId) %}
{% endif %}

{% set entries = query.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
   ------Entry Content-----
{% endfor %}

{% if entries %}
  {# Increments `offset` by the value of `limit` and swaps itself out on click #}
  <button class="orange-button" sprig s-vars="offset: {{ offset + limit }}" 
    s-target="this" s-swap="outerHTML">
    <p>Load More</p>
  </button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This worked great! However, the load more button at the bottom no longer disappears when there are no more entries to load

Comment: @JustinKendall - changed the code above for you, the button should disappears as before now.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Oli You're a legend!